# Symfony 3 REST API POST validation

Tags: rest, api, symfony, validation

What is the "best" way to handle entities validation in a Symfony3 REST application?

I know that I could use Form to do it and use its already existing validators (required, email type, repeat type, ...).

Might I also use the entity repository or another service to validate, serialize, unserialize my entities, thus having all the entity IN/OUT logic at the same place? But then how should I handle validation during both creation and update when data might not all be present?

Any thought?

Comment: By the way, I find it weird to use the Form because I don't care about the representation (UI) of the date but only on its real value. e.g. I don't want to validate a checkbox or radio, but only that the given value is really a boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your inputs. I'll use the Doctrine `Assert` validators to handle the validation and the `Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation` class.

Regarding the Symfony3 documentation I think this is probably the best option.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html

Comment: Mind the fact, that if you send array instead of string in your API call, validation may (depending on exact validators) fail with exception instead of validation error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Process the request through a Controller
2. Use a Form to process that request
3. Build custom validators or leverage existing on the FormClass
4. Using your controller (#1) handle `PUT` and `POST` and `PATCH` separately with unique actions.
5. Serialize/deserialize your request/response in the controller *OR* using a handler that the controller (#1, #4) hands the request off to.

Answer (score -1):

another way, in my project, i not apply form for entity, maybe you need this way

> Helper: [image]
>   Base function : [image]
>
> Create action in controller
>   [image: create action]
>
> Update Action in controller
>   [image: update action]